# Numpy array comprehensions, where problem

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a little problem with np.where and I can't find any answers in google so here's my question. Consider I have these arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1, 0.5, 2], [5, 0.25, 9], [-1, 0.77, 3]])
b = np.array([0.6, 0.2, 0.6])
```

What I want is: `if a[x, 1] < b[x] then a[x, 0] else a[x, 2]`.
So I want to get this:

```
[1, 9, 3]
```

I thought code like this would work, but it doesn't

```
np.where(a[1] < b, a[0], a[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
np.where(a[:,1] < b, a[:,0], a[:,2])
```

You need to specify which axis you want to make the comparisons and take the elements, else as a default it will use the 0 axis, check the values for:

```
a[1]
a[1,:]
a[:,1]
```

See that the first two are the same (the default behaviour), and you are looking for the third.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question :) and I have another problem. In my code array `a` has 5 elements in a row, and on the same condition I want to take first 2 elements or last 2 elements and when I use code like this `np.where(a[:,2] < b, (a[:,0], a[:,1]), (a[:,3], a[:,4])` I get array with only 2 rows and my goal is that every row has 2 elements this `(a[:,0], a[:,1])` or `(a[:,3], a[:,4])`

Comment: A bit more tricky, but try this: `np.where(a[:,1].reshape(1,-1) < b.reshape(1,-1), a[:,0:2].T, a[:,2:4].T)`, that is if I understood what your desired output, even if not, you can probably take it from there :)

Comment: Something didn't work, but I eventually resolved the problem thanks :). Could u recommend some source of knowledge to get around python and numpy? I get rlly overwhelmed with this language ... .

Comment: https://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/  this look like a nice place to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help good sir, bless!